# export all Jenkins data to a CSV format

Tags: jenkins

I am new to Jenkins but learning for the purpose of seeing what our jobs do (there are so many that nobody has a handle on it right now).

I would like to export all the Jenkins data as a CSV where each row is a Jenkins job and each column represents a field in the configuration form for that job.  Is this possible?

P.S. I have found threads on exporting and importing between Jenkins servers but not this particular method, which is more for analysis.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about CVS but you can export all jobs into an XML containing all its configuration using the command line tool.

`http://jenkins-server/cli` lists all the commands of the jenkins-cli tool. Download `jenkins-cli.jar` locally to use. Be sure you have the proper credentials. `Overall/Read` account permission is required.

In order to retrieve all the jobs' configurations, first retrieve the list of all jobs with the following:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://jenkins-server list-jobs
```

Then, to obtain the complete data of each job, do:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://jenkins-server get-job JOB1 > JOB1.xml
```

For more information on jenkins-cli tool, see [this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI).

Comment: That makes sense as the data is not symmetrical.  Now I just need to use the output of `list-jobs` and loop through and do them all in bulk :)

Comment: I am having a problem now with `get-job`.  I can list-jobs OK, but who-am-i says I am anonymous.  I try logging in using `login` parameter (and know my login is correct) and get this: `hudson.security.UserMayOrMayNotExistException: Unable to retrieve the user information without bind DN/password configured`

Comment: Either there is something wrong with the server's configuration or you provided an invalid `--username` to the `login` command. Check the server's access control settings.